# Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so

Tags: android, ubuntu, java

In eclipse, I open a android project, click the layout xml file. then pop the dialog "Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so" and the file didn't be opened.

How can I open the xml normally, it seems jdk6 is installed with error or the path is wrong.

os is ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-6-jre
```

should do the job (see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1099777) for example)