# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1:

Tags: java

I am running my automation test project in Gitlab pipeline. I am getting the exception as "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I tried multiple solution for installing and updating the packages but no luck
Tried solutions :

- dpkg --add-architecture i386
- apt-get update
- apt -y install libxext6
- apt-get -y install libbz2-1.0:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386
- apt-get -y install libxrender1 libxtst6 libxi6

could you please suggest?

Comment: Are you trying to build the native lib (creating the .so file in the fly) or trying to make use of the pre-built version of it? In the first case, make sure your test-automation tool supports it; in the second case, make sure the presence of your lib file in the appropriate location.

Comment: Thank you reply @Hack06. I could able to get the solution by installing libxtst6

Comment: Glad to be helpful. I've made an answer out of my comment, so you can accept it ;)

Comment: Note that `apt-get update` doesn't actually update any packages, it only updates the package list. Follow it up by `apt-get upgrade` to actually install any packages with updates available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to build the native lib (creating the .so file in the fly) or trying to make use of the pre-built version of it? In the first case, make sure your test-automation tool supports it; in the second case, make sure the presence of your lib file in the appropriate location.

Answer (score 2):

After running `java -jar languagetool.jar` I received the same error as your question mentions:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921034/cant-load-library-usr-lib-jvm-java-6-openjdk-jre-lib-i386-xawt-libmawt-so) similar question, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-6-jre
```

Which returned:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done Package openjdk-6-jre is not available, but
> is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is
> missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
> However the following packages replace it:   icedtea-netx
>
> E: Package 'openjdk-6-jre' has no installation candidate

Hence, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -y icedtea-netx
```

And that resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably encountering this error because you do not have the `libawt_xawt.so` package in your `/usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/amd64/` directory.

To fix the problem, follow these steps:

1- Update the package index:

`sudo apt-get update`

2- Install openjdk-11-jre deb package:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre`

source [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/21.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/openjdk-11-jre_11.0.11+8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue, and I this fixed it:

`apt-get install libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386`